# Filling an arraylist with Objects of two generic types

Tags: java, class, generics, arraylist, data-structures

I have created a class `Entry` that looks like this

```
public class Entry<S,E>{
    S Item1;
    E Item2;
    Entry(S s, E e){
        this.Item1=s;
        this.Item2=e;
    }
}
```

I want to make an `ArrayList` of this type. What should it look like?

How can I add an `item1` but keep `item2` `null` for later on?
(in other words fill the array with `item1`s and fill in `null` for the `item2`s, the array would look like [1]Item1,null , [2]Item1, null , etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like any other list.

[`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a typed-interface. Let's name its generic type `T`. This means our interface is `List<T>`. Here, we want to have a list of `Entry<S, E>` whatever `S` and `E`; so in this case, `T = Entry<S, E>`. Therefore, the list is `List<Entry<S, E>>`.

Sample code:

```
List<Entry<S, E>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Entry<>(item1, item2));
list.add(new Entry<>(item1, null));
```

To take a more concrete example where `S = String` and `E = Integer`:

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Entry<>("foo", 1));
list.add(new Entry<>("bar", null));
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was confused about thank you i was over thinking this way too much haha